# Find which sum of any numbers in an array equals amount

Tags: math

I have a customer who sends electronic payments but doesn't bother to specify which invoices. I'm left guessing which ones and I would rather not try every single combination manually. I need some sort of pseudo-code to do it and then I can adapt it but I'm not sure I can come up with a good algorithm myself. . I'm familiar with php, bash, and python but I can adapt.

I would need an array with the following numbers: [357.15, 223.73, 106.99, 89.96, 312.39, 120.00]. Those are the amounts of the invoices. Then I would need to find a sum of any combination of two or more of those numbers that adds up to 596.57. Once found the program would need to tell me exactly which numbers it used to reach the sum so I can then know which invoices got paid.

Comment: What will you do when there is more than one combination yielding the target sum?

Comment: Alternative solution: Send them a payment reminder, claiming that you did not receive payment for each of the bills. That should trigger them to tell you that they DID pay. Then tell them you cannot find any matching payment and also no payment referring to any of the bills. Then they should react by explaining the sum. Repeat next time. At some point they accept that you are (in their eyes, not what I think of you) stupid and need everything explained in detail.

Comment: I do not see how math can help you with this. It is more about algorithms and lucky you, because a pure math question would be off-topic here. But I am afraid that brute forcing is the only way I can think of.

Comment: In the past I have had to pester them for weeks on end until I finally got the answer to my question and I will continue to do so but it would be nice to have an alternative solution because that takes a lot of my time. Yes brute forcing is exactly what I want to do

Comment: This is a problem called zero-one assignment. You have a1, a2, a3, ... and you want to find x1, x2, x3, ..., each of which is 0 or 1, such that x1 a1 + x2 a2 + x3 a3 + ... adds up to the target value. With a small number of values to combine, brute force is workable. Let's say there are n values to combine. Start by enumerating the 2^n combinations, (0, 0, 0, ...), (1, 0, 0, ...), (0, 1, 0, ...), (1, 1, 0, ...), up to (1, 1, 1, ...). Now compute the sum for each combination. Compare the sums to the target and see which, if any, are within a tolerance (let's say a dollar).

Comment: It might help to multiply all the numbers by 100 (i.e. work with whole cents instead of fractional dollars). If you want to have a lot of fun with it, a web search for "constrained optimization zero-one assignment" should find some resources. Good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to the Subset Sum problem and can be solved using a similar approach to the typical brute-force method used for that problem. I have to do this often enough that I keep a simple template of this algorithm handy for when I need it. What is posted below is a slightly modified version<sup>1</sup>.

This has no restrictions on whether the values are integer or float. The basic idea is to iterate over the list of input values and keep a running list of every subset that sums to less than the target value (since there might be a later value in the inputs that will yield the target). It could be modified to handle negative values as well by removing the rule that only keeps candidate subsets if they sum to less than the target. In that case, you'd keep *all* subsets, and then search through them at the end.

```python
import copy

def find_subsets(base_values, taget):
    possible_matches = [[0, []]] # [[known_attainable_value, [list, of, components]], [...], ...]
    matches = [] # we'll return ALL subsets that sum to `target`
    for base_value in base_values:
        temp = copy.deepcopy(possible_matches) # Can't modify in loop, so use a copy
        for possible_match in possible_matches:
            new_val = possible_match[0] + base_value
            if new_val <= target:
                new_possible_match = [new_val, possible_match[1]]
                new_possible_match[1].append(base_value)
                temp.append(new_possible_match)
                if new_val == target:
                    matches.append(new_possible_match[1])
        possible_matches = temp
    return matches


find_subsets([list, of input, values], target_sum)
```

This is a very inefficient algorithm and it will blow up quickly as the size of the input grows. The Subset Sum problem is NP-Complete, so you are not likely to find a generalized solution that will work in all cases and is efficient.

---

<sup>1: The way lists are being used here is kludgy. If the goal was to simply find *any* match, the nested lists could be replaced with a dictionary, and we could exit right away once a match is found. But doing that will cause intermediate subsets that sum to the same value to also map to the same dictionary slot, so only one subset with that sum is kept. Since we need to report *all* matching subsets (because the values represent checks and are presumably not fungible even if the dollar amounts are equal), a dictionary won't work.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations(t,r)` to list all combinations of `r` elements in array `t`.

So we loop on the possible values of `r`, then on the results of `itertools.combinations`:

```py
import itertools

def find_sum(t, obj):
  t = [x for x in t if x < obj] # filter out elements which are too big
  for r in range(1, len(t)+1):    # loop on number of elements
    for subt in itertools.combinations(t, r):  # loop on combinations of r elements
      if sum(subt) == obj:
        return subt
  return None

find_sum([1,2,3,4], 6)
# (2, 4)
find_sum([1,2,3,4], 10)
# (1, 2, 3, 4)
find_sum([1,2,3,4], 11)
# none
find_sum([35715, 22373, 10699, 8996, 31239, 12000], 59657)
# none
```

**Rounding errors:**

- The code above is meant to be used with integers, rather than floats.
- To use with floats, replace the test `sum(subt) == obj` with the more forgiving test `sum(subt) - obj < 0.01`.

**Relevant documentation:**

- [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)